# Comando cron sem usar senha para acessar banco de dados MySQL

Tags: mysql, cron, password

Ultimamente venho recebendo avisos relacionados a uma `cron` que criei em um site para atualizar determinados dados de uma tabela de um banco MySQL.

O erro é o seguinte:

> Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be
> insecure.

Como faço para corrigir esse problema, visto que preciso acessar o banco de dados para atualizá-lo?

```
mysql --user=usuario --password='senha' --database=bancodados --execute="UPDATE protocolos P INNER JOIN reclamacao R SET P.status = 'Em atraso' WHERE P.id = R.id_protocolo AND P.status='Em aberto' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(),R.data_registro) >= 20
```

Alguém saberia como fazer essa mesma ação sem precisar colocar a senha no comando?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `mysql_config_editor` para configurar o acesso e evitar passar o login/senha abertos na linha comando:

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=usuario --password=senha
```

Depois basta executar sem a necessidade de passar login/senha:

```
mysql --execute="UPDATE protocolos P INNER JOIN reclamacao R SET P.status = 'Em atraso' WHERE P.id = R.id_protocolo AND P.status='Em aberto' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(),R.data_registro) >= 20
```

Aqui a referência do comando: [mysql-config-editor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html)

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, parece que isso poderá resolver meu problema, a questão agora é: Como configurar o acesso via mysql_config_editor dentro do cPanel?

Comment: você pode usar o `mysql-config-editor` para salvar as configurações em um arquivo, e pode passar o caminho do arquivo com as configurações para o `cron` usando o parâmetro `--defaults-extra-file`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um arquivo `.my.cnf` no diretório `$home` do seu usuário, para configurar o acesso ao banco de dados `mysql` e evitar passar o login/senha expostos na linha de comando, as instruções contidas aqui podem ser feitas em qualquer sistema operacional baseado em unix:

Acesse o diretório $home do seu usuário, e crie um arquivo oculto `.my.cnf`:

```
cd $home
touch .my.cnf
```

O conteúdo do arquivo `.my.cnf` deve ser:

```
[mysql]
user=<usuário>
password=<senha>
```

Substitua os valores `<usuario>` e `<senha>` pelas credenciais que deseja utilizar para acessar sua instância do banco de dados.

Após criar este arquivo basta utilizar o comando `chmod` para restringir o acesso de leitura do arquivo apenas ao seu usuário.

```
chmod 0600 .my.cnf
```

Após fazer essas configurações será possível acessar sua instância do banco de dados diretamente sem a necessidade de passar usuário e senha via a linha de comando.

```
mysql
```

Para mais informações de utilização consulte a [`documentação`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/password-security-user.html)